# Android collapsable Toolbar menu icons disappearing

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

So I've implemented collapsable Toolbar inside my app and in Java class I override onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_share:
                break;
            case R.id.action_addToFavorites:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And now when I open the activity I can see the menu icons and do stuff with them until the toolbar is colapsed. When user colapses the toolbar the icons disappears.

Second problem, with using the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` method i get back button of black color instead of white so now I'm using this method:

```
tToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_arrow_back));
```

My question for this problem is how to handle click events for this navigation icon? This icon also disappears when toolbar colapses and leaves the left padding like it's there, but it's not.

Here's my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.darioradecic.topmusicandartists.Details">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewDetailsTopGlobalSongs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using old version of Support Library(23.0.1) ? If yes then see if the icons doesn't disappear with the latest version .

To use white color back button , add this to style.xml

```
<style name="MyToolbarLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout xml , add the style .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/tToolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/MyToolbarLight"
/>
```

Your icon is disappearing because you haven't set collapse mode for the toolbar so it doesn't stay fixed when you start scrolling, simpy add this to your toolbar :

```
 app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

**Note:** if you're including your toolbar layout you must specify (or repeat) the width and height values, collapseMode will not be enough:

```
<include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

Comment: I'm using the latest 23.2.1 support library and setting a custom style solved the black back arrow button problem, but icons still disappear when toolbar is colapsed